# Cordova plugin with framework with Appdelegate

Tags: ios, cordova, cordova-plugins, appdelegate, ios-frameworks

I have created a framework with a native sdk that the company I work has for push notifications. I have an Appdelegate inside this framework because there are some files that use it. I have added this framework as a plug in for a Cordova test application but as I see I can use only one of the two AppDelegates that exist now(one in framework and one in cordova app). I am trying to use only the framework's AppDelegate but to do this I must somehow use CDVAppDelegate. The problem is that the app in initialization doesn't run the correct didFinishLaunchingWithOptions function and I can't see the default first page of the cordova app. I have this files inside the plug in:

AppDelegateExtension.m

```
#import "xxxSDK/AppDelegate.h"
#import "xxxSDK/xxx.h"
#import "MainViewController.h"
#import "MyPlugin.h"

@implementation AppDelegate (MyPlugin)
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication*)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary*)launchOptions
{
    #if (DEBUG == 1)
      [xxx launchWithAppUUID:@"1256fbeb638b4426a98e4bacbc5f56f5" launchOptions:launchOptions];
    #else
      [xxx launchWithAppUUID:@"1256fbeb638b4426a98e4bacbc5f56f5" launchOptions:launchOptions];
    #endif

    [[xxx sharedService].pushManager registerForRemoteNotifications];
    [[xxx sharedService].pushManager resetBadge];
    MyPlugin.myPlugin.viewController = [[MainViewController alloc] init];
    
    [MyPlugin.myPlugin application:application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
    return YES;
}
```

MyPlugin.h

```
#import <Cordova/CDVAppDelegate.h>

@interface MyPlugin : CDVAppDelegate
    // Public static method
    + (CDVAppDelegate*) myPlugin;
@end
```

MyPlugin.m:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "MyPlugin.h"
#import "MainViewController.h"

@implementation MyPlugin

// Private static reference
static CDVAppDelegate* myPlugin;

// Public static method
+ (CDVAppDelegate*) myPlugin {
    return myPlugin;
}
@end
```

Inside the framework the AppDelegate.h is this:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>
@end
```

I have tried declare MyPlugin as a CDVPlugin too but the problem didnt get solved. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Because `AppDelegateExtension.m` is a category of the `AppDelegate` class it extends the original class rather than implementing a subclass, so any methods you implement in your category which already exist in the main class (i.e. [`AppDelegate.m`](https://github.com/apache/cordova-ios/blob/master/bin/templates/project/__PROJECT_NAME__/Classes/AppDelegate.m) auto-generated by Cordova) will be replaced.

So in this case your `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` in `AppDelegateExtension.m` is replacing [`didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` in `AppDelegate.m`](https://github.com/apache/cordova-ios/blob/master/bin/templates/project/__PROJECT_NAME__/Classes/AppDelegate.m#L33).

TL;DR: You need to [swizzle the method](https://nshipster.com/method-swizzling/) to avoid destroying the original method:

```
@implementation AppDelegate (MyPlugin)
+ (void)load {
    Method original = class_getInstanceMethod(self, @selector(application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:));
    Method swizzled = class_getInstanceMethod(self, @selector(application:swizzledDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions:));
    method_exchangeImplementations(original, swizzled);
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication*)application swizzledDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary*)launchOptions {
{
    #if (DEBUG == 1)
      [xxx launchWithAppUUID:@"1256fbeb638b4426a98e4bacbc5f56f5" launchOptions:launchOptions];
    #else
      [xxx launchWithAppUUID:@"1256fbeb638b4426a98e4bacbc5f56f5" launchOptions:launchOptions];
    #endif

    [[xxx sharedService].pushManager registerForRemoteNotifications];
    [[xxx sharedService].pushManager resetBadge];
    MyPlugin.myPlugin.viewController = [[MainViewController alloc] init];
    
    [MyPlugin.myPlugin application:application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
    return YES;
}
```

You can see an example of this in [cordova-plugin-firebasex](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-plugin-firebasex/blob/master/src/ios/AppDelegate%2BFirebasePlugin.m).

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply! Actually I am trying to access CDVAppdelegate's function at the line [MyPlugin.myPlugin application:application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i did this:

```
@implementation AppDelegate (MyPlugin)
+ (void)load {
    Method original = class_getInstanceMethod(self, @selector(application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:));
    Method swizzled = class_getInstanceMethod(self, @selector(application:swizzledDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions:));
    method_exchangeImplementations(original, swizzled);
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication*)application swizzledDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary*)launchOptions
{
    #if (DEBUG == 1)
      [Warply launchWithAppUUID:@"1256fbeb638b4426a98e4bacbc5f56f5" launchOptions:launchOptions];
    #else
      [Warply launchWithAppUUID:@"1256fbeb638b4426a98e4bacbc5f56f5" launchOptions:launchOptions];
    #endif

    [[Warply sharedService].pushManager registerForRemoteNotifications];
    [[Warply sharedService].pushManager resetBadge];
    CDVAppDelegate *appDelegate = [[CDVAppDelegate alloc]init];
    [appDelegate application:application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
    return YES;
}
```

CDVAppdelegate's didFinishLaunchingWithOptions is running but I can not see in my device index.html view. My sdk runs properly but the cordova app is not running at all.
I assume that the thing is that AppDelegate : UIResponder  can not support what I want to do and I am starting to believe that what I want can not be implemented.